# Relaciones entre tablas con Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hola yo no se que me pasa con las relaciones, pero siempre tengo problemas con ellas.

**Modelo product**
 Como un producto solo puede tener una categoria y una subcategoria pongo `belongsTo`.

```
protected $table = 'products';
    protected $primaryKey='id';

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'id');
    }

    public function subcategories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Subcategory', 'id');
    }
```

**Modelo category**
 Aquí pongo el `hasMany` por que una categoría puede tener más de un producto. Aquí hay que hacer caso a `public function producto()` el otro es para conectar las categorías con las subcategorias.

```
protected $table = 'categories';
    protected $primaryKey='id';

    public function subcategories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Subcategory', 'category_id');
    }

    public function producto()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'categoria');
    }
```

**Modelo Subcategory** 
 Aquí como un subcategoria puede pertenecer a más de un producto pongo `hasMany`, Como en el modelo de Category, solo hay que hacer caso a `public function producto()`.

```
protected $table = 'subcategories';
    protected $primaryKey='id';

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'id');
    }

    public function producto()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'subcategoria');
    }
```

**Luego en el controlador:**

```
$productos = Product::with('categories', 'subcategories')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(12);
return view('productos')->with(["productos" => $productos);
```

**En la vista**

```
@foreach ($productos as $pro)

  {{ $pro->categories->name }}
  {{ $pro->subcategories->name }}

@endforeach
```

Cuando hay un único producto, me funciona perfectamente, pero en cuanto hay más de uno ya me dice que la propiedad `name` no existe.

Answer (score 3):

**Importante**

Considero que tienes mal planteada la relación de tus tablas por que por ejemplo indicas que:

> Una producto puede pertenecer a una subcategoria y una subcategoría puede tener varios productos, pero en uno de tus párrafos dices que **un producto puede estar en varias subcategorías** (*lo cual me lleva a pensar que este escenario se resuelve pero con una relación de muchos a muchos*), por que de lo contrario en la tabla de productos el mismo nombre de producto se podría estar repitiendo N veces lo cual habla de un problema de normalización.

Por otro lado siguiendo con el ejercicio actual sugiero estos cambios:

Los nombres que les des a las relaciones te ayudarán en gran medida a identificar semánticamente cuando usarlas y evitar posibles colisiones entre modelos y confundirte por los nombres que les estás dando.

Por tanto deberías:

En el modelo **`Product`**

- Las relaciones **`categories`** y **`subcategories`** deben pasar a singular entiendiendo que un producto solo pertenece a una categoria y a una subcategoría

En el modelo **`Category`**

- La relación **`producto`** debe pasar a plural entendiendo que una categoría puede tener N productos asociados

En el modelo **`Subcategory`**

- La relación **`producto`** debe pasar a plural entendiendo que una subcategoría puede tener N productos asociados

Además:

Trata de ser uniforme en el lenguaje usado, por que por un lado veo que unas relaciones están en inglés y otras en español (*o bien dejas uno o dejas el otro pero no mezcles ambos*)

Además considero que debe cambiar el como haces la carga ambiciosa de las relaciones, puesto que tratas de obtener a producto con todas su(s) categoría(s) y  subcategorías y dado que el modelo **`Category`** tiene relación con el modelo
**`Subcategory`** entonces puedes acceder con la sintaxis de: `(relacion.otraRelacion)`

Tu consulta se puede construir así:

```
$productos = Product::with('category.subcategories') //con los cambios de nombres de relaciones que hice
                    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                    ->paginate(12);
```

Que si imprimimos su resultado nos daría una estructura mas o menos así:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "product N",
        "category_id": 1,
        "subcategory_id": 1,
        "created_at": "2020-09-01T20:25:25.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-09-01T20:25:25.000000Z",
        "category": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "category N",
            "created_at": "2020-09-01T20:21:07.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-09-01T20:21:07.000000Z",
            "subcategories": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "subcategory N-1",
                    "category_id": 1,
                    "created_at": "2020-09-01T20:23:06.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-09-01T20:23:06.000000Z"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "subcategory N-2",
                    "category_id": 1,
                    "created_at": "2020-09-01T20:23:06.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-09-01T20:23:06.000000Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Las relaciones que estoy invocando ya van con el cambio de nombres que te mencioné mas arriba.

Una vez que eso cambia entonces debes considerar que la consulta te puede estar regresando:

- Una colección para los registros de Producto (*esto lo debes iterar por que esta colección tiene N objetos vinculados*)
- Un objeto para los registros de categorías (*asumiendo que un producto pertenece solo una categoría*)
- Una colección para los registros de subcategorías (*esto lo debes iterar por que esta colección tiene N objetos vinculados*)

Dado eso entonces no puedes acceder a sus elementos de forma directa así: `$variable->propiedad` como si de un objeto se tratara (al menos NO en todos los casos).

Puedes probar con una iteración así:

```
@foreach($productos as $producto)
    {{ $producto->algo }} //atributos del modelo producto
    {{ $producto->category->name }} //atributos del modelo category
        @foreach($producto->category->subcategories as $subcategory)
            {{ $subcategory->name }} //atributos del modelo subcategory
        @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**Referencia**

- [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

*Nota final.*

Para que identifiques si tus relaciones requieren o no argumentos extra cuando las construyes, por favor lee a detalle la documentación vinculada.

Comment: No consigo entender bien lo de los modelos y relaciones!! Ahora después de cenar lo pruebo, gracias @BetaM

Comment: No me funciona @BetaM `Trying to get property 'name' of non-objec`

Comment: En cuál foreach te sale?

Comment: Lo he tenido que echar atrás y hacer `joins` no podia esperar a solucionarlo. Mañana con calma lo miro y te especifico más

Comment: Si gustas pública tu solución

Comment: No no @BetaM quiero hacerlo con las relaciones de laravel, mañana lo comprobare de nuevo

Comment: @Miguel me parece excelente así tengo tiempo de mirar mi solución y editar si es necesario

Comment: Genial,! mañana hablamos que estoy cansado y quiero dormir jajaj

Comment: Por favor checa a detalle mi edición

Comment: Woow @BetaM eres increible con tu respuestas, bravo! Luego lo pruebo que ahora tengo una reunión con unos clientes. Luego cuando termine me pongo a ello. Muchas gracias por tu atención

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que una categoría puede tener varias subcategorías y a su vez una subcategoría puede tener varios productos, si es así la relación directa entre categorías y productos la deberías hacer con hasManyThrough.

Model Category

```
protected $table = 'categories';
protected $primaryKey='id';

public function subcategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subcategory', 'category_id');
}

public function productos()
{
    return $this->hasManyTrougth('App\Product', 'App\Subcategory');
}
```

Luego, buscás en el controlador la categoría o categorías que te interesan y deberías de poder mostrar los productos que pertenecen.

```
$categorias->productos
```

El foreach podría ser:

```
    @foreach($categorias as $categoria)
      @foreach($categoria->productos as $producto)
          {{ $producto->categories->name }}
          {{ $producto->subcategories->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Hola gracias por tu comentario @FabianM pero no quiero sacar los productos de una categoria, quiero sacar todos los productos y imprimir su categoria y subcategoria

Comment: Modifiqué la respuesta para que te sirva. Pero también podrías hacerlo seleccionando todos los productos en el controlador sin agregar relaciones con categorías o subcategorías, esas relaciones sólo las mostras después en la vista.